# Writing a test expression that fits a certain type inference in F#

Tags: f#, expression, type-inference

I'm brushing up on some key points in F# and my instructor has recommended a few exercises to help us grasp the concepts (*not* homework). He has given us certain types that the F# compiler would infer when given a sample expression, and we are supposed to be able to come up with an expressions that would provide it. The ones I have got somewhat stuck on are the following:

```
('a -> 'b) -> ('b -> 'c) -> ('a -> 'c)
```

and

```
('a -> 'b) * ('c -> 'a) -> ('c -> 'b)
```

The first one is of course the function composition operator `(f o g)(x)`, or `(>>)`, but I cannot think of anything that would have the second. Would anyone have any suggestions? Also, alternatives to the first one would be quite appreciated as well.

Comment: [reverse composition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353882.aspx)?

Comment: @Daniel - it needs to be uncurried, too: `(<||) (<<)`.  Probably more readable as an explicit lambda...

Comment: @Daniel That is indeed the correct one! `fun (f,g) -> fun x -> f(g(x));;`. Thank you very much. If you wish, post your comment as an answer and I will accept it right away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like [reverse composition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353882.aspx) (`<<`) and, as kvb pointed out, it needs be uncurried.